# Seeedstudio SIM900 Arduino GPRS Shield V2.0 does not reply response to terminal

Tags: serial-port, arduino, at-command, gprs, arduino-ide

I have Arduino Leonardo and [Seeedstudio GPRS Shield v2.0](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0). Both of them working seamlessly. 
Following tutorial on main gprs shield [link here](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0), I've succesfully compiled the following code to arduino:

```
//Serial Relay - Arduino will patch a 
//serial link between the computer and the GPRS Shield
//at 19200 bps 8-N-1
//Computer is connected to Hardware UART
//GPRS Shield is connected to the Software UART 


#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial GPRS(7, 8);
unsigned char buffer[64]; // buffer array for data recieve over serial port
int count=0;              // counter for buffer array 
void setup()
{
  GPRS.begin(19200);      // the GPRS baud rate   
  Serial.begin(19200);    // the Serial port of Arduino baud rate.

}

void loop()
{
  if (GPRS.available())            // if date is comming from softwareserial port ==> data is comming from gprs shield
   {
    while(GPRS.available())        // reading data into char array 
    {
      buffer[count++]=GPRS.read(); // writing data into array
      if(count == 64)break;
  }
    Serial.write(buffer,count);    // if no data transmission ends, write buffer to hardware serial port
    clearBufferArray();            // call clearBufferArray function to clear the storaged data from the array
    count = 0;                     // set counter of while loop to zero
  }
  if (Serial.available())          // if data is available on hardwareserial port ==> data is comming from PC or notebook
    GPRS.write(Serial.read());     // write it to the GPRS shield
 }
void clearBufferArray()            // function to clear buffer array
{
  for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
     { buffer[i]=NULL;}            // clear all index of array with command NULL
}
```

the code above take AT Command from serial as input and pass it to gprs module. So, I could type something like: "ATD + +1XXXXXXXX" which code to call numbers, and it worked. The problem is I can't get response from gprs module serial, it's just blank after. I read that the response to serial terminal should be: "OK". My questions are:

a. Is there something I missed? I want to get response written to the terminal.

b. I want to make http request, does someone has experience how to do it? What I mean is this gprs opening website blablablabla.com/cs/blabla.php?name=blabla

thx before

Comment: When you say that "ATD + +1XXXXXX" worked, what do you mean by "worked"?  What result did you see?

Comment: @SList i didn't see any response, i knew it worked because i got call from arduino shield

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your SIM900 is in "Result Codes Suppressed" mode. When in this mode, it simply doesn't send result codes such as "OK".

Try to send it an "ATQ0" command to get it to transmit result codes. (Take a look at the ATQ command in the AT Command Manual).

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried sending ATQ0 and got nothing, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert on this stuff, but...
At no point do I see a line which would print or display data.

Example:

Assuming you established something like a variable: `int inByte=0` at the beginning

like your `buffer[count++]` or `BufferArray()`, which I'm somewhat unfamiliar with

then you could retrieve the data by using

```
Serial.println(inByte);
```

or

```
GPRS.println(inByte);
```

which would display this info in your COM port window

So....?
something like

```
Serial.println(buffer[count++]);
```

or

```
GPRS.println(buffer[count++]);
```

Both of which will compile BTW

Answer (score 0):

Examples with 7 pin with Leonardo do not work. With 10 pin (need connect a wire instead jumper) work ok.